# Is there a way to navigate or filter Launchpad using type-selection?

Tags: macos, launchpad

Launchpad quickly becomes a mess once you have many apps installed. Especially seeing the fact that stuff like 'Microsoft Silverlight' (which you most likely will never run manually, but runs as a plugin) hooks itself into the Launchpad as well.

I have a couple of 'Crap' and 'Stuff' folders in which I store apps like these. Still, I'd like to navigate my Launchpad faster. When a person opens Launchpad, he/she usually *knows* what app he/she wants to start; it would be a *lot* easier if I'd be able to press the first character of this app, and Launchpad would automatically create a custom filtered screen for me.

Apparently, there is no such feature, but are there perhaps any plans to integrate this into OS X in a later stage? If not, are there any plugins that might be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can just forgo launchpad and try [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/). It's navigated by keyboard anyway, so you can configure it to just show apps when you type something into the bar. Because, as you said, a user probably knows the app their searching for, theres not really a point to look at a grid of all the options in Launchpad, when you know you are only going to need one.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to your application by keyboard anyway, you can easily

- press <kbd>Cmd-Space</kbd> to activate Spotlight
- start typing the name of the application
- press <kbd>Return</kbd> as soon as Spotlight found the application

You may get a few false hits at the beginning but Spotlight learns about your Preferences quite fast.